# Remove time & date dependency on os in java application

Tags: java

Have you ever encounter such a scenario:

Need to test some date related functionality of your software, the software rely on OS to get current date, so we have to change the date of OS, but date & time is actually a critical service in any OS, changing date & time of OS may cause problems, for example some application server check last-modified date to decide whether to recompile JSP files.

Is there any smart way to handle such problems, like set date & time on JVM level or application level ?

Comment: This is one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792000/how-can-i-mock-java-time-localdate-now

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the purpose of the java.time.Clock class.

Comment: Another related Question: [Unit testing a class with a Java 8 Clock](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27067049/642706)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Java 8 and the classes of `java.time`, you can use [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html). At normal application run time you can then inject and use the normal system clock provided by `Clock.systemDefaultZone()`, for tests you can inject a `Clock` instance with a fixed time, for example provided by [`Clock.fixed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) or subclassing `Clock` if you need more control.

You would then need to change your code to something like:

```
// Inject this value somehow, eg using Spring
private Clock clock;

public LocalDateTime methodThatGeneratesTime() {
    return LocalDateTime.now(clock); // Instead of just LocalDateTime.now()
}
```

Comment: We can't use java 8 right now, but I will try ThreeTen Backport with JDK 6.

Comment: The [`java.time.Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class offers other altered-clock implementations in addition to `fixed`. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26570951/642706) to a duplicate Question for a list with descriptions. So, not likely any need to roll-your-own override of `Clock`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Good to know, I haven't had the chance to use it much yet, and I have seen a colleague using a subclass in one of our tests, so I assumed that for some use cases it might be necessary.