# How to create a Java 8 Clock for a specific date

Tags: java-8, java-time

Regarding date dependent unit tests I am figuring out the right way of creating a Java 8 Clock for a specific date. According to the approach proposed in [Unit testing a class with a Java 8 Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27067049/1140754), I am trying it with the [`Clock.fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) method. However, I am not realizing a short way of doing it.

Is this the right and best way of creating a Java 8 Clock for a specific date?

#### version 2 (according to suggestions of [@Meno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253334/how-to-create-a-java-8-clock-for-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment73577690_43253334), [@LakiGeri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253334/how-to-create-a-java-8-clock-for-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment73576057_43253334) and [@basil-bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253334/how-to-create-a-java-8-clock-for-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment73726059_43253334))

```
private static Clock utcClockOf(int year, int month, int day) {
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    Instant inst = LocalDate
            .of(year, month, day)
            .atStartOfDay(offset)
            .toInstant();
    return Clock.fixed(inst, offset.normalized());
}
```

#### version 1

```
static Clock clockOf(int year, int month, int day) {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    long days = now.toEpochDay();
    long secs = days*24*60*60;
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochSecond(secs);
    return Clock.fixed(inst, ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Comment: why dont you use this: `now.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);` to create instant? On the other hand, LocalDate not handle hour / minute / sec.. I recommend you to use `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: A clock is not designed to yield a calendar date but an instant. If you just want to have an injection mechanism for calendar dates then you might consider the interface `java.util.function.Supplier<LocalDate>`. Otherwise - in case of a `Clock`-implementation, you  have to think about timezone effects i.e. specifying which explicit timezone you want else your "fixed" clock would not really be fixed.

Comment: why do you need to create a fake Clock?

Comment: @holi-java Are you suggesting to mock Clock with an auxiliary mocking library, such as Mockito?

Comment: @LakiGeri I will use your suggestions to create an instant.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I will consider the timezone when creating a Clock instance and I updated the auxiliary function `clockOf()` to `utcClockOf()`

Comment: @MiguelGamboa I think you maybe miss something in your domain language. There is a OO princple: "Tell, don't ask".

Comment: @holi-java Sorry, but I am not understanding your point of view. I am aware of the "Tell, don't ask" principle, but I am not getting your idea.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa chpater20:listen to the test in [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) there is an example in section 2 & 3.you  can download GOOS from [this](http://www.cs.umss.edu.bo/doc/material/mat_gral_137/Addison.Wesley.Growing.Object.Oriented.Software.Guided.by.Tests.Oct.2009%20(1).pdf).

Comment: Pass that `offset` to `atStartOfDay` rather than `toInstant`