# LocalDateTime.of returns null

Tags: java, datetime, mockito, java-time, powermockito

I am trying to Unit test code that uses `java.time.LocalDateTime`. I'm able to get the mock working, however when I add time (either minutes or days) I end up with a `null` value.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ LocalDateTime.class })
public class LocalDateTimeMockTest
{
    @Test
    public void shouldCorrectlyCalculateTimeout()
    {
        // arrange
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
        LocalDateTime fixedPointInTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 11, 21, 28, 47);
        BDDMockito.given(LocalDateTime.now()).willReturn(fixedPointInTime);

        // act
        LocalDateTime fixedTomorrow = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1); //shouldn't this have a NPE?

        // assert
        Assert.assertTrue(LocalDateTime.now() == fixedPointInTime); //Edit - both are Null
        Assert.assertNotNull(fixedTomorrow); //Test fails here
        Assert.assertEquals(12, fixedTomorrow.getDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

I understand (well I think I do) that `LocalDateTime` is immutable, and I would think I should get a new instance instead of the `null` value.

Turns out it is the `.of` method that is giving me a `null` value. Why?

Comment: Did you try to run code without mocks? It's likely that powermockito is creating the issue.

Comment: And consider to rethink using PowerMock(ito) in the first place ;-)

Comment: When mocking a Java "system" class (like `java.time.LocalDateTime`), PowerMock requires that the non-system class *using* that class gets listed in `@PrepareForTest` (as already pointed out in other answers). But the biggest mistake in tests like this, in my experience, is to even entertain the idea of mocking dates/timestamps or the system clock. If the SUT uses `LocalDateTime.now()`, then it most likely should also allow a date object to be given from outside (by the caller code), which would make it trivial to write the test without any mocking. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic):

> Use `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to mock **all** methods of this class.

and:

> Note that you can mock static methods in a class even though the class is final. The method can also be final. **To mock only specific static methods of a class refer to the [partial mocking](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockPartial) section** in the documentation.
>
> To mock a static method in a system class you need to follow [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockSystem) approach.

You told it to mock all the static methods, but didn't supply a mock for the `of()` method.

Solution: Either add mock for the `of()` method, or change to use partial mocking, so the `of()` method is not mocked.

Basically, **read and follow the instructions of the documentation**.

Answer (score 4):

[@Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167472/7605325) correctly explains about PowerMock usage (and you also figured out [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167198/7605325)).

I'd just like to add a different approach. In order to test the current date/time, you could use a `java.time.Clock`. With this class, you can create a [fixed clock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) (a `Clock` that always returns the same current date/time) and [use it in your test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067049/unit-testing-a-class-with-a-java-8-clock).

With this, there's no need to mock static methods (I had to remove the PowerMock annotations from the test class). The only difference is that the clock must be passed to the `now()` method:

```
@Test
public void shouldCorrectlyCalculateTimeout() {
    // create a clock that always returns the same current date/time
    LocalDateTime fixedPointInTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 11, 21, 28, 47);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(fixedPointInTime.atZone(zone).toInstant(), zone);

    // use the clock in now() method
    LocalDateTime fixedTomorrow = LocalDateTime.now(clock).plusDays(1);

    // assert (use equals() instead of == because it doesn't return the same instance)
    Assert.assertTrue(LocalDateTime.now(clock).equals(fixedPointInTime));
    Assert.assertNotNull(fixedTomorrow);
    Assert.assertEquals(12, fixedTomorrow.getDayOfMonth());
}
```

I had to use `equals()` method (instead of `==`) to compare the dates, because `now(clock)` creates a new instance, although all instances will correspond to the same date/time (and that's what matters, IMO).

---

**PS:** In the code above I'm using the JVM default timezone (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`). The only problem is that it [can  be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

In this specific code, the timezone part is being ignored, so you could use any zone and this wouldn't make much difference - unless you get a combination of a timezone and local date when a Daylight Saving Time changeover occurs, which can produce unexpected results.

If you don't want to rely on that, you could replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead (UTC doesn't have any Daylight Saving effects). In this case, you could create your clock like this:

```
ZoneOffset utc = ZoneOffset.UTC;
Clock clock = Clock.fixed(fixedPointInTime.toInstant(utc), utc);
```

Answer (score 1):

So the PowerMockito.mockStatic was messing with the next line of code. Simply moving the instantiation of fixedPointInTime to execute before the mockStatic....makes it all work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your class like

```
public class SomeClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = getCurrentLocalDateTime(); 
        System.out.println(now);
    }

    private LocalDateTime getCurrentLocalDateTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

And in the `Test` Class you use:

```
@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

In TestCase:

```
LocalDateTime tommorow= LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1);

SomeClass classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new SomeClass());

PowerMockito.when(classUnderTest, "getCurrentLocalDateTime").thenReturn(tommorow);
```