# How to mock new Date() in java using power mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, mockito, powermock

I am currently have a requirement where in, need to mock new Date() to a specific date for all the test cases.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date NOW = sdf.parse("2015-09-26 00:00:00");
   whenNew(Date.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(NOW);
}
```

So i used the above code to mock it , but still when i see the output of the test results, i could still see the actual "new Date()" is executed.

So i added this in @before block in all the test files. So can you please help to know if I am missing anything?

Comment: Since you're using Java 8, the preferred approach is to inject a `Clock` object; this is exactly why the API was developed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067049/unit-testing-a-class-with-a-java-8-clock for more information on how to use `Clock` so that unit testing is easier.

Comment: As I understand, the code you are testing is using `Date`. That’s unfortunate since the class is long outdated and poorly designed. You will want to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. It’s so much nicer to work with, though of course I cannot tell how fast you can afford to migrate. Among many nice features the modern API has good support for unit testing so you won’t need mocking anymore.

Comment: To the extent that you cannot replace the `Date` class yet you may use `Date.from(Instant.now(yourClockForTestingOrTheRealClock))`.

Comment: A) we would need a [mcve] B) most likely, you are simply not following the required steps to mock `new()` ... as the answer points out, you simply have to specific things to get it to work (which are all nicely documented btw)

Answer (score 2):

The classes under test (where `new Date()` is being called) need to be prepared for testing (because PowerMockito needs to do bytecode manipulation to intercept the constructor calls).

See [the documentation for the `@PrepareForTest` annotation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html)

Also [this page has a good overview on how to do this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)