# assertEquals the returned value of method which returns a dynamic value

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

Problem description-
I am trying to test my login method which returns an object of **AuthenticationResponse** which contains four fields-username,jwt token,refresh token,and expiry Time for the jwt token.

```
public class **AuthenticationResponse** {
    private String userName;
    private String jwtToken;
    private Instant expiresAt;
    private String refreshToken;
}
```

My Login method(method to be tested) is in AuthService class.

```
@Service
public class AuthService
{
    public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
       //some logic going on...
       Instant expiresAt=Instant.now().plusMillis(900*1000);
        //some logic going on
        return authenticationResponse;

    }
}
```

My Test class goes like this->

```
public class AuthServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private AuthService authService;
    @Test
    public void loginTest_whenCredentialsAreCorrect()
    {
      ///some logic goes over here...
      AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse=new AuthenticationResponse();
      authenticationResponse.setJwtToken("jwttest");
      authenticationResponse.setUserName("jack");
      authenticationResponse.setRefreshToken("jwt1");
    authenticationResponse.setExpiresAt(Instant.now().plusMillis(900000));
     assertEquals(authenticationResponse,authService.login(loginRequest));
  
    }
}
```

I have written my logic inside the method which assigns the value for expiresAt field like this

```
Instant expiresAt=Instant.now().plusMillis(900*1000)
```

**Now,in  how can I assign the same value for that field(expiresAt) while creating the object of AuthenticationResponse to assert it with the returned value from method.**

I can't get any way to match the value of this field with the value returned from the method.

My Test fails showing this output:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:

Expected :AuthenticationResponse(userName=jack, jwtToken=jwttest, expiresAt=2020-07-30T13:40:45.828Z, refreshToken=jwt1)

Actual   :AuthenticationResponse(userName=jack, jwtToken=jwttest, expiresAt=2020-07-30T13:40:45.840Z, refreshToken=jwt1)

Is there any way around to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the expiresAt value.
Please refer below link to find various methods of doing it.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-override-system-time

Comment: Thanks for the help.Powermock is still not supported with Junit5.I found an answer over. here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067049/unit-testing-a-class-with-a-java-8-clock